# How to create linux system account with access only to specific namespace in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

On my Linux servers, I have kubernetes cluster. Many developers using this cluster. 
I would like to create Linux system accounts for users with access only to specific kubernetes namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the linux account in your host.
2. Create TLS certification for the account.

> ```
> openssl genrsa -out ${account-name}-key.pem 2048 
> openssl req -new -sha256 -key ${account-name}-key.pem -out ${account-name}.csr -subj "/CN=${account-name}"
> openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in ${account-name}.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out ${account-name}.pem -days 365
> ```

3. Create kubeconfig to connect to the apiserver with the TLS certifications. something like:

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Config
> clusters:
> - cluster:
>     certificate-authority: /home/account-name/ssl/ca.pem
>     server: https://master-ip
>   name: k8s
> contexts:
> - context:
>     cluster: k8s
>     user: account-name
>   name: admin
> current-context: admin
> users:
> - name: account-name
>   user:
>     client-certificate: /home/account-name/ssl/account-name.pem
>     client-key: /home/account-name/ssl/account-name-key.pem
> ```

4. Give the user proper priviledge with RBAC, like full priviledge to a namespace:

   > ```
   > apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
   > kind: RoleBinding
   > metadata:
   >   name: account-name-admin
   >   namespace: namespace-name
   > roleRef:
   >   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   >   kind: ClusterRole
   >   name: edit
   > subjects:
   > - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   >   kind: User
   >   name: account-name
   > ```